# Repeating code number of times

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm learning Racket and I need some help. How do I run this function only 4 times instead of running it infinitely?

```
(define loop
  (λ ()
    (define delay (random 5))
    (digital-write led1 HIGH)
    (sleep delay)
    (displayln delay)
    (digital-write led1 LOW)
    (sleep delay)
    (loop)))
```

Comment: If you can add arguments to your function, look at the answer provided with an accumulator. Otherwise, you would need to use mutation.

Comment: Gasp! Don't advocate mutation to a new Racket user! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way is to use `for`.

```
(define (do-it-once)
  (define delay (random 5))
  (digital-write led1 HIGH)
  (sleep delay)
  (displayln delay)
  (digital-write led1 LOW)
  (sleep delay))

(for ([n 4]) 
  (do-it-once))
```

Comment: This is a better way to do it, in general. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you find you need to do this often, you can expand on soegard's `for`-based answer with a macro for making your code clearer:

```
(define-syntax-rule (repeat num-times body ...)
  (for ([n num-times])
    body ...))

(repeat 4
  (define delay (random 5))
  (digital-write led1 HIGH)
  (sleep delay)
  (displayln delay)
  (digital-write led1 LOW)
  (sleep delay))
```

This macro makes your intention explicit. This is useful for avoiding confusion when someone reading your code sees `[n 4]`, because if your loop is complicated it might not be immediately apparent that you're only using the variable `n` for counting the loops. This is most definitely overkill if you only need it in one or two places however.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question in the general case, you could use an accumulator:

```
(define (loop arg)
    (if (eq? arg 0)
        "Done"
        (loop (sub1 arg))))

(loop 4)
```

This will loop `arg` times. Every call will decrement `arg` by one. Once it is 0, you return whatever value you desired.  Of course, this is a silly example as written, but demonstrates a general pattern you can use.

Note: the use of accumulator is a misnomer here, an accumulator usually accumulates a value over several calls...